# JavaFX AlertType Class Not Found When Running Wrapped Jar (JavaFX + SpringBoot + Gradle + launch4j)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, javafx, launch4j

I'm developing a JavaFX application using Spring Boot and gradle build.
When I run the executable generated jar it runs successfully, but when I generate an exe file using launch4j and run it, I'm getting the following error in console during the execution, when the app trying to display an Alert
(header type in launch4j was set to console so I can see the exceptions):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException .........
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.control.Alert$AlertType
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 59 more
```

When I change the exe file extension to .jar everything is ok!

This is the first time I developed such application using Spring Boot,
my other applications work perfectly when I launch them as exe file.

Any idea?

Comment: I have tried to use another version of JRE for running the exe, and it's working now. Probably the one I used before doesn't include Alert.

Comment: According to the docs, the Alert class was added in Java(FX) 8 update 40. So if what you say is true, you were using an ancient version of Java 8.